# React ScrollIntoView not working from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that has a button. When that button is clicked, it should scroll to a grid in the child component, but it is not working. There hasn't been any errors. This is what I have in the parent component:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someState: undefined,
    };
    this.ref_grid = React.createRef();
  }

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        someState: newState,
      }, () =>
      {
        if (this.ref_grid.current !== null) {
          this.ref_grid.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
         return (
          <>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={() => this.handleClick()} 
            >Click me!</Button>
            <ChildComponent
            forwardRef={this.ref_grid}
            />
         </>
       );
   }
}
```

In the child component I have the ref:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    const {
      classes
    } = this.props;
    return (
       <Grid container spacing={3} ref={this.props.forwardRef}>
       </Grid>
   )
  }
}
```

I am new to React, so I am not sure if this is the right approach. Would appreciate if anyone has any idea or example how to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When the ref attribute is used on a custom class component, the ref object receives the mounted component's instance as its current instead of html element. That is to say, `ref.current` receives the instance of ChildComponent and there is no scrollIntoView method defined in ChildComponent.

Comment: Where should I define the method? Can you give me an example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-architecture-gdnx3

Comment: Also you can use `forwardedRef` api in functional component. [https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried following your example and in Mozilla is working, but in Chrome is not working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Work well on my Chrome. Maybe you need debug according to your specific situation.

Comment: You are right, this is a different situation when I execute the scroll in componentDidUpdate(). This is the code I am using: ` componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.ref_example.current !== null && this.state.buttonClicked) {
      this.ref_example.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
      })
        this.setState({
          buttonClicked: false
        })
    }

Comment: This is working in Mozilla, but not in Chrome. The problem is setState inside componentDidUpdate, but I am not sure how to check if the button has been clicked without setState?

Comment: No any logic errors in your code snippets.
I had re-edited my codesandbox's example: [codesandbox.io/s/little-architecture-gdnx3](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-architecture-gdnx3), using setState in componentDidUpdate is also work well for me. Maybe you should debug the condition expression in componentDidUpdate lifecycle.

Comment: I've found out that if I remove behavior: 'smooth' option from scrollIntoView, it works. Do you have any suggestion how to get it to work in Chrome, but still keep this behavior?